# Weird ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, jar, executable-jar

This line of code is working fine when I debug in eclipse.

```
this.primaryStage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) { 
                            InputManager.Instance().addEvent(keyEvent); 
                        }
                });
```

When I export it into .jar ussing my own code (not script), it throws a rather long exception.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(
Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/Game$1
        at test.Game.start(Game.java:62)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163
(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(Unknown S
ource)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Game$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 10 more
Exception running application test.Game
```

Yet when I export it the same way, but with the handler commented out, it works fine.
I have tried root.addEventHandler, root/primaryStage.setOnKeyPressed, declaring the handler separately, ..

Can you spot the ex reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> export it into .jar using my own code

Your "own code" is not doing it right, because it is not including the `test/Game$1.class` file in the `.jar` file.

Your class is called `Game` in the `test` package. When the class uses anonymous classes, those classes must be given a name in order for the `.class` file to be created (also need the name internally). The name of such files can be anything, but the *current* scheme is to name it after the defining class, adding a sequence number after a `$` sign, so the first anonymous class is called `Game$1.class`, the second would be called `Game$2.class`, and so on.

That is why, when you compile `Game.java`, you end up with 2 files: `Game.class` and `Game$1.class`. *Both* of those files must be added to the `.jar` file.

You shouldn't rely on this naming convention, if at all possible, because it could change in the future, and other compilers might do it differently.

Comment: Meaning that I need to add every occurence of the Game*.class in /bin/ to the jar? I only add getClass().getResource("Game.class") as an entry to the jar file. Would this fetch the other ones aswell? Is there a way to od the code without the annonymous classes?

Comment: Found out i can just add Game and every Game$i.class with i++ until it's not found. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That covers anonymous classes, but will not include all the other types of nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFound exception is usually due to your CLASSPATH environment variable not getting set correctly.

The JVM must have transversed everywhere from the CLASSPATH directory but was not able to find your compiled *.class and java jar files. One way to fix this would be to use the -cp option from the java binary. Or you can set your CLASSPATH environment to the directory where your java files are sitting.

Things run fine in Ecplipse because the classPath set to the workspace and the IDE has got this handled for you.

> Read here for more information about CLASSPATH.
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html